# JQUERY issue mouseLeave - sliding animation

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, slide, mouseleave

Don't no why my jsfiddle doesn't work

This is my code :

```
<div id="dentisterie">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="dentisterie-left"> <img src="img/dentisterie.png"> </div>
        <div class="dentisterie-right">
            <div class="dentisterie-right-container">
                <h2>DENTISTERIE</h2>
                <p>Le catalogue STONER regroupant toutes les références destinées aux cabinets dentaires. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 $('#dentisterie > .overlay').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('overlayhover');
                $('.overlay').toggleClass('index');
                $('.dentisterie-right-container')
    .toggleClass('overlaytoggled')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0, right: '100px'}, 500)
    .mouseleave(function() {
    $('.dentisterie-right-container').css('right','-500');
  });              
})




.dentisterie-right-container {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0.0;
    position: relative;
    right:-500px;
}

.overlaytoggled {
    visibility: visible;  
}

.keepfaraway {
    position:relative;
    right:-500px;
}
```

In the header :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dentisterie-right-container')
          .css('display', 'block')
          .animate({opacity: 1.0, right: '-200px'}, 2000);
      });
    </script>
```

I want that on hover, the `.dentisterie-right-container` appear by sliding from right and disappear when mouse leave.

Issue : my container is sliding on the first hover, but doesn't go back to `right:-500px;` when mouse left. 
So when I hover again, no more slide effect.

I would really like to understand why / how to do that as I'm looking forward to improve my jquery skills

Thanks !!

Comment: Where is HTML code ?

Comment: sorry thought was not necessary
i've edited

Comment: You're using `css` instead of `animation`